# Multiple file upload to Django 1.7 and Python 3 admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Python.

I'm interesting in uploading multiple files in Django Admin at once with ajax and saving them to a separate model. And I didn't found yet any ready solution that will work in Python 3. Please help me - how can I do this?